# Ebean on Play! is running out of connections

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

trying to stress test my new Play! java app. after making a few db requests i start getting failures and [out of connections] errors. and even when i try to use my MySql console i cant because all my connections are taken up by Play!

What is the right way to solve this?
Does Ebean have some kind of connection pool?

Answer (score 3):

wasn't easy, but google finally brought me to the play framework site and this

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SettingsJDBC

excellent explanation, or rather, copy paste of how to configure ebean. you put those configurations into your application.conf and everything should work.